# PHP Notice: Undefined variable: customerName

Tags: php, mysql

Not sure why im getting this error in my logs.

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: customerName 
here is line 74:
$arrOrderDetails = $purchaseOrder->load($customerName);

this im returning "$customerName" from the instance of another class
here is that code:

```
public function load($customerName){
$orderDetails = array();
//Adding first order detail
$orderData = array
    ('order_id' => 1, 
    'customer_name' => 'Lancaster Landscapes',
    'description' => 'Golf Balls-Titlest DT Solo', 
    'quantity' => 13,
    'price' => 33,
    'total' => 432.25
    );
$orderDetail = new OrderDetail($orderData);
$array_push($orderDetails, 1, $orderDetail);

return $orderDetails;
```

}

I will still be adding more elements to the array.
Any suggestions?

Comment: `$array_push(...)`? Isn't that `array_push(...)`? Also, why are you passing `$customerName` to the method if you never use it?

Comment: instead of giving us the function you should tell us where $customerName has been defined/initialized. If you call YourObject::load() on $customerName in line 74 then $customerName should be set somewhere before that statement.

Comment: Why do you pass that parameter anyway? It does not get used within the function.

Comment: please forgive me, i'm new to programming and php in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just a notice, aka wont break the code, however if you want to clean it up , prior to $customername being assigned you include

```
 $customername='';
```

That notice should go away